# what3word map API call

Tags: jquery, html, json, api, dom

I'm sitting here with a location API called what3word and I'm finding myself in trouble trying to show the the map in the DOM. The API connection is working perfectly well, I see everything in the console with `console.log()` but I don't understand what should I add to see the JSON response data on the DOM (so far in the DOM I see [object Object] and in the console I see:

> ```
> Object { crs: Object, words: "effekt.mikroklimat.kurser", bounds: Object, geometry: Object, language: "sv", map: "http://w3w.co/effekt.mikroklimat.ku…", status: Object, thanks: "Thanks from all of us at index.home…" }
> ```

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-cCueBR6CsyA4/9szpPfrX3s49M9vUU5BgtiJj06wt/s="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script>
      var settings = {
        "async": true,
        "crossDomain": true,
        "url": "https://api.what3words.com/v2/forward?addr=effekt.mikroklimat.kurser&key=5QM8EG7T&lang=sv&format=json&display=full",
        "method": "GET",
        "headers": {}
      }

      $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = response;
      });
    </script>
    <style>
      #test {
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="test"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I followed the documentation but there is nothing about to how to display the data in the DOM. Should I add a content-type in "headers"? I tried with "Content-Type": "text/html; charset=utf-8" but no luck, what am I missing?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to display? you are getting back an object with properties on it... I would recomend you to put the script inside of a script file. use firebugg or chromes built in inspector(press f12) and then you can debug the response. If you want to present the data in one of the properties then simply: "response.words"

Comment: Hi! In the console i get a couple of objects with arrays in it, one of those objects has a lot of coordinates so i think I could be able to display those coordinates in a form of map in the DOM (that I guess it should be included in the response from the api?) or should I create a map and in some way insert the response there? I should get something like this: https://map.what3words.com/ Thanks for answer!

Comment: Thank you for your help @Ra3IDeN I could get the 3 words with response.word and the link to the map with response.map and I used Leaflet to "draw" the map in the DOM!